# Selecting file using JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, file, jfilechooser

Will these lines below help me to browse to a file and store the file content into the `myFile` variable?

Also, can someone please tell me what the following means?

```
JFrame frame = null;
```

and

```
(System.getProperty( "user.dir" )
```

**Code:**

```
    JFrame frame = null; 
    JFileChooser fChoose = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty( "user.dir" ) );
    int returnVal = fChoose.showOpenDialog(frame);
    File myFile  = fChoose.getSelectedFile();
```

Comment: If you can't answer your question by yourself, you should read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).

Comment: `(System.getProperty( "user.dir" )`  One thing that means is that the author of the code obviously does not understand `JFileChooser` very well.  It **defaults** to the `user.dir`.  Also note the Java Docs for [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) are a great place to start answering this question..

Comment: Is the file which's contents you want to store containing text?

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone. @cdMinix yes the file contents text.

Comment: @user3180947 If you want to read the files contents [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) could help you.

Comment: @cdMinix but i would like to allow the user to browse for a file. Will buffered reader help me do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read text from the file, this would be your way to go:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "ISO-8859-1"));
String line;
while ((line = stream.readLine()) != null) {
     //save your lines to an array or list       
}
stream.close();
fis.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
JFrame frame = null;
```

means you're declaring a JFrame variable and assigning it to `null`.

This

```
System.getProperty( "user.dir" )
```

means you're getting the user working directory.

See also:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

On your main question, you should read some tutorial about JFrame and JFileChooser.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html